# How to increase the execution time of ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, mysql

I have written a query which is taking more then 30 sec.

My Code:

```
MySqlConnection myConnection = new    MySqlConnection(ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["CollectiveIntelligence"]);

    string query = @"SELECT TBL.NAME1,
                           TBL.NAME2 
                      FROM (SELECT MLD1.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME1,
                                   MLD2.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME2 
                              FROM FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD1 
                              JOIN FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD2 
                             WHERE MLD1.LOGIN_NAME < MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
                          ORDER BY NAME1,NAME2) TBL
                     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_NAME1,
                                              USER_NAME2 
                                         FROM CONNECTION C
                                        WHERE (C.USER_NAME1 = TBL.NAME1 AND C.USER_NAME2 = TBL.NAME2));";

    MySqlCommand myCommand = new MySqlCommand(query, myConnection);

    //Open Connection
    myConnection.Open();
    myCommand.CommandTimeout = 0;
    MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();

    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    dt.Load(reader);

    GridView1.DataSource = dt;
    GridView1.DataBind();

    myConnection.Close();
    reader.Close();
```

Error Occurring

```
    MySqlDataReader reader = myCommand.ExecuteReader();
```

Error Message: **Timeout expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding**

how to increase the execution timeout of asp.net so that it will execute the query/

[EDIT]

when i click the explain its showing like this

```
id select_type  table   type   possible_keys   key              key_len   ref   rows   Extra
1, SIMPLE,      MLD1,   ALL,   ,               ,                 ,         ,    295,   Using temporary; Using filesort
1, SIMPLE,      MLD2,   ALL,   ,               ,                 ,         ,    295,   Using where; Using join buffer
1, SIMPLE,      C,      index, ,               INDEX_CONNECTION, 94,       ,    30754,   Using where; Using index; Not exists
```

[/EDIT]

Please Help

Thanks in Advance

Comment: In your query you are joining the tables without any condition which is causing a cross join and long execution time. Try optimizing your query first, there is no need to increase execution time..

Comment: @Meherzad: i have already asked this question how to reduce the time
link:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616638/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-join-query-in-mysql

Answer (score 0):

I would add it to your config file so you can control this per application. So, within the connection string add

```
Timeout=60;
```

Example:

"Data Source=source;Initial Catalog=cata;Timeout=60;etc"

Then, within your code, you can call it.

```
myCommand .CommandTimeout = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["CommandTimeOut"]
```

I would also suggest you though, that you consider if your SQL script is efficient! There is no point changing these settings if it could be resolved else where. Run the command locally on the server and see if it just takes that long to rule out any other issues.

To change the time out in Visual Studio open "Tools -> Options" and then under Database Tools - Query and View Designers. Here, you can change the timings or even disable the option of cancelling long running query's.

There is also a time out within the Table and Database Designers section too (still under Database tools)

Comment: i tried with 60 sec its not working.I read somewhere that if we write 0 then it will execute till the end means no execution time

Comment: Are you getting this error from debug mode in Visual Studio or in live? Do you get the same error when you run this query locally?

Comment: debug mode in visual studio. not uploaded to live

Comment: @user1926138 How long does your query take when you run it within MySql

Comment: yes.In mysql workbench also its showing error.i have placed a question . please go through it .in mysql also its taking more time so its showing error like **MySQL server has gone away** http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15631189/error-code-2013-lost-connection-to-mysql-server-during-query

Comment: Requirement to write query.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616638/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-join-query-in-mysql

Comment: @user1926138 I'm convinced the issue is your SQL statement, I would personally never change the timeout unless dealing with huge amounts of data as this is getting round an issue instead of solving it. Penfold's answer seems to better than mine so I would focus on that

Answer (score 0):

You can modify it in IIS too,

```
select your website > advanced settings >limits > connection Time out
```

you must considerate performance of your query

Comment: where advanced setting is present 

can you please give the path so that i can reach there i didn't find the advance setting in my case

Comment: click on your website on the left pane in IIS , you can see "advanced properties" on the right pane

Answer (score 0):

Your query is performing a select with a filter, sorting the results set, then filtering it again. It would be better to filter it first then apply the sort to the reduced result set. This would reduce the time your query takes so you don't get the timeout.

```
SELECT MLD1.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME1, MLD2.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME2 
FROM FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD1 
JOIN FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD2 ON MLD1.LOGIN_NAME < MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT USER_NAME1, USER_NAME2 
                FROM CONNECTION C
                WHERE C.USER_NAME1 = MLD1.NAME1 AND C.USER_NAME2 = MLD2.NAME2)
               )
ORDER BY MLD1.LOGIN_NAME, MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
```

### UPDATE

Based on your other [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616638/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-join-query-in-mysql) the correlated sub-query can be removed and replaced by a sub-query.

```
SELECT MLD1.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME1, MLD2.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME2 
FROM FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD1 
JOIN FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD2 ON MLD1.LOGIN_NAME < MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
WHERE (MLD1.LOGIN_NAME + MLD2.LOGIN_NAME) NOT IN 
                     (SELECT USER_NAME1 + USER_NAME2 FROM CONNECTION C )
ORDER BY MLD1.LOGIN_NAME, MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
```

### UPDATE 2

As the above was slower you could also try the following.

```
SELECT MLD1.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME1, MLD2.LOGIN_NAME AS NAME2 
FROM FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD1 
JOIN FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS MLD2 ON MLD1.LOGIN_NAME < MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
LEFT OUTER JOIN CONNECTION C ON C.USER_NAME1 = MLD1.NAME1 AND C.USER_NAME2 = MLD2.NAME2
WHERE C.USER_NAME1 is null and C.USER_NAME2 is null
ORDER BY MLD1.LOGIN_NAME, MLD2.LOGIN_NAME
```

You may need to add an index to FEDERATED_M_LOGIN_DETAILS.LOGIN_NAME, CONNECTION.USER_NAME1 and CONNECTION.USER_NAME2  to improve performance.

Comment: Please Go through this link this is my requirement.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15616638/how-to-remove-duplicate-rows-from-a-join-query-in-mysql

Comment: second query(with + operator) is taking more time then the 1st query with exist.

Comment: The 3rd query is also taking 30.498sec in my mysql workbench.

Comment: Have you tried adding an index to the columns in MySql as I suggested?

Comment: yes i have added index to the columns.
i have updated my question please review.